# Injective map between power series ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, power-series

Suppose $k$ is a field and let $n > m$. Does there exist injective homomorphisms 
$$ k [[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]] \rightarrow k[[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m]]\ ?$$

Comment: no, it is from the "false beliefs" thread at MO.

Comment: Taken from http://mathoverflow.net/a/25231

Answer (score 3):

This answer is (a revision of) Simon Wadsley's comment posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/25231/23950) with the only goal to remove this question from the unanswered queue.

Let $k$ be a countable field, and take a map $k[[x,y,z]] \to k[[u,v]]$ that sends $x$ to $u$, $y$ to $uv$ and $z$ to $uf(v)$ for some $f∈k[[v]]$. It isn't hard to see that only for countably many choices of $f$ can the kernel  possibly be non-zero.